# Adding custom textarea to Joomla article backend

Tags: php, html, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I'm adding additional TextArea to Joomla's Article in the administrator.

I added the form, actually saving the content into Database, but it saves only usual text "asdasaf" but not an image with html like: `<p><img smth ></p>`

Well I want new textarea to act just like Joomlas default text area.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

To get HTML form post data you need to get this data in following way

```
$data = JRequest::getVar( 'textAreaName', 'defaultValue', 'post', 'string', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW );
```